# Whimsy or Whimsicality?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, speech

When would I use the word "Whimsicality" over "Whimsy"?

The definitions I've read do not draw a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no answers have been posted yet, I took a stab at it.

Merriam Webster says Whimsy is

> a sudden impulsive and apparently unmotivated idea or action

and defines Whimsicality as

> an inclination to sudden illogical changes of mind, ideas, or actions

WikiDiff and other sites support this distinction:

> As a noun whimsy is a quaint and fanciful idea a whim playfully odd
>   behaviour. 
>   As a verb whimsy is to fill with whimsies or whims; to
>   make fantastic; to craze.
>
> As a adjective whimsical is  given to whimsy; capricious; odd;
>   peculiar; playful; light-hearted or amusing.

In other words, Whimsicality is the inclination to whimsy, or the state of being given to whimsy.

A little confusing but I hope this answer doesn't come across as stupid, lazy, or pretentious.